# Python program giving got multiple values for argument 'self'

Tags: python

I have below Python program  passing `**locals()` values to method argument, when I run this program its giving

`TypeError: SendEmail.render_template() got multiple values for argument 'self'`

Error message, If I write this function out side of the class, it works.  May I know why its not working inside the class?

```
from pathlib import Path

import jinja2


class SendEmail:

    def __init__(self, to_address):
        self.sender = "noreply@gmail.com"
        self.to_address = to_address

    def render_template(self, **kwargs):
        template_file = ""

        search_path = str(Path.cwd())
        template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath=search_path)
        template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
        templ = template_env.get_template(template_file)
        return templ.render(**kwargs)

    def prepare_email(self):
        html = self.render_template(**locals())
        print(html)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_list = 'test@gmail.com'
    obj = SendEmail(to_list)
    print("Preparing E-mail")
    obj.prepare_email()
    print("Completed")
```

Comment: Because inside `prepare_email`, `self` is a local which you're explicitly passing, in addition to the `self` the method will receive anyway.

Comment: It seems that `render_template()` doesn't use its `self` argument. Perhaps you could use `@staticmethod` to solve the problem.

Comment: What was `**locals()` supposed to accomplish, anyway?  There are no local variables defined at that point in time that seem useful for rendering the template.  I assume that you want access to things like `sender` and `to_address` - but those aren't locals, they're instance attributes.  `**self.__dict` might be closer to what you need.

Comment: @jasonharper my original application I have variable like this `app_name="test"`. with variable also its giving same error.

Comment: @quamrana  I made it `@staticmethod` now this line giving same error `return templ.render(**kwargs)`

Comment: Did you remove the `self` parameter?

Comment: Yes, I removed it.

Comment: If anything you’ll want to remove `self` from the dict you get from `locals`!

Comment: @deceze  removing `self` from dict worked, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze response. Here is the working code.

```
from pathlib import Path

import jinja2


class SendEmail:

    def __init__(self, to_address):
        self.sender = "noreply@gmail.com"
        self.to_address = to_address

    def render_template(self, **kwargs):
        template_file = "email-template.j2"

        search_path = str(Path.cwd())
        template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath=search_path)
        template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)
        templ = template_env.get_template(template_file)
        return templ.render(**kwargs)

    def prepare_email(self):
        appid = '12345'
        temp_local = locals()
        del temp_local['self']
        html = self.render_template(**temp_local)
        print(html)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_list = 'test@gmail.com'
    obj = SendEmail(to_list)
    print("Preparing E-mail")
    obj.prepare_email()
    print("Completed")
```